# wpf ContentPresenter wont enable/disable

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, contentpresenter

I've overridden a `ComboBox` in order to add an extra button at the end of the combo - i'm using this to help navigate round my application.

Its a M-V-VM App that has an Edit-Save/Cancel mechanism that disables or enables the controls depending on  whether or not the user is in 'edit mode'.  I wanted my navigation button to always be available whether the View is enabled or disabled.

To achieve this I'm binding the `ToggleButton` and the `ContentPresenter` to a `IsEditable` property on my Model.

The toggle button enables and disables as expected but the Text of the combo stays enabled.

As the text is delivered by the `ContentPresenter` and the `ContentPresenter` has an `IsEnabled` property I can't understand why it wont disable?

Can anyone assist?  Thanks Andy

```
<Style TargetType="local:EntityCombo">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:EntityCombo" >
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"
                        Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource EntitySelectedButton}" Command="{TemplateBinding EntitySelected}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"></Button>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource SelectionBoxItem}" 
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid 
          Name="DropDown"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
            x:Name="DropDownBorder"
            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one, but I've been knee-deep in WPF long enough to be very persistent. :) 
After suggesting this in my last comment my insanity drove me to test it out and it is indeed the problem:

The template sets `ComboBox.Foreground` based on `ComboBox.IsEnabled`, but you want to style the content based on `DataContext.IsEnabled`, so you would need to style the `ContentPresenter` itself. But you cannot style `ContentPresenter` because it inherits from `FrameworkElement`, not Control. But you can replace the `ContentPresenter` with a `ContentControl` and style it with the appropriate triggers for your disabled appearance.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the IsEditable is on my ViewModel which is the DataContext.  The ToggleButton works fine i.e. Enables and Disables - its just the ContentPresenter won't enable/disable.

Comment: Sorry -- I didn't read that part closely enough. These binding quirks can be so aggravating. Have you tried enabling trace sources (PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High") for that binding to see what's actually happening when it tries to get the value?

Comment: Even if I just set the IsEnabled on the ContentPresenter to False, i.e. I don't bind at all - then the Text still shows as Enabled! :(

Comment: These binding quirks can drive you mad. I'm trying to cross reference your template against my own ComboBox override, but they're different in that you're using a ContentPresenter for your display item whereas I'm using a TextBox since it's an editable combo, so I bind IsReadOnly to the same property on the parent to disable text entry. Can you post the template you're using for SelectionBoxItem in the ContentPresenter?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not using a custom template for the SelectionBoxItem, I was thinking that my xaml would be using the default ComboBox one?

Comment: It depends on whether the text is editable, which I've been assuming to be the case because of wanting to disable Text, but now that I'm comparing our XAML I realize your template is based on the non-editable case. Doh! :) That explains what's happening. The template sets ComboBox.Foreground ofbased on ComboBox.IsEnabled, but you want to style the content based on View.IsEnabled. Unfortunately you can't style the ContentPresenter itself because it's a FrameworkElement and not a Control, but if you change the ContentPresenter to a ContentControl and apply the appropriate style it should work.